# Como criar um botão(button) ou um link(a) para realizar o download de um determinado arquivo?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, download

Preciso criar um botão que ao clicar seja realizado o download e não aberto em uma outra aba ou janela. Podendo ser qualquer tipo de arquivo tanto imagem, pdf, música entre outros.

Comment: Estou usando Ruby on Rails

Comment: Existe uma maneira simples, mas que por enquanto só funciona no Chrome: `<a href="url" download="nome-do-arquivo">Baixe!</a>`. A maneira garantida é forçar o download pelo servidor.

Comment: @bfavaretto, vc tem algum artigo alguma coisa mostrando como fazer isso?

Comment: Sobre o atributo: http://davidwalsh.name/download-attribute, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a, http://caniuse.com/#feat=download. Sobre forçar no servidor, com ruby/rails eu não sei, mas certamente tem como fazer.

Comment: Ok, muito obrigado!

Comment: @JeffersonAlison: dê uma olhada aqui: https://www.google.se/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=ruby+on+rails+download+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: Você pode tratar seu arquivo com um controlador diferente, se você não quer lidar com as configurações do servidor HTTP. Para isso você poderia utilizar o [send_file](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Streaming/send_file)

Comment: Opa, obrigado @Sergio! Vou procurar ai.

Comment: @JeffersonAlison se encontrar uma boa coloque aqui.

Comment: Criei um exemplo que pode lhe ajudar https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/74750/disponibilizar-arquivo-para-download-via-javascript

Answer (score 2):

Determinei um método que receberá o parâmetro download de um `link_to()`, dessa forma ele serviria para diversos tipos. Para seguir esse exemplo eu tenho um arquivo chamado: *javascript_the_good_parts.pdf* localizado em */public/*.

**Crie uma controller chamada Pages(app/controllers/pages_controller.rb):**

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def index    
  end
  def download
    send_file "#{Rails.root}/public/#{params[:file_name]}"
  end
end
```

**Adicione em suas rotas(config/routes.rb):**

```
root 'pages#index'
get 'download'=> 'pages#download'
```

**E como página(app/views/pages/index.html):**

```
<%= link_to "Fazer Dowload" ,:action => :download, :file_name => "javascript_the_good_parts.pdf" %>
```

**Screenshot Exemplo:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Existe o atributo `download` em [HTML5](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp) que pode ser usado assim:

```
<a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro você tem que colocar um iframe hidden e sem src na sua aplicação

```
<iframe name="iframe_download" class="hidden"></iframe>
```

Agora você pode colocar o link para download com o target para o iframe oculto

```
<a href="/caminho/para/download.pdf" target="iframe_download">Clique para baixar</a>
```

Espero ter ajudado