# Disponibilizar arquivo para download via javaScript

Tags: javascript, download

Tenho uma aplicação em javascript onde o usuário consegue visualizar determinados arquivos do servidor. Gostaria de saber como disponibilizar estes arquivos para download, algo como um botão "Salvar como".
Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Apenas fazer um `window.location.href='caminhoDoArquivoParaDownload';` não resolve?

Comment: Conseguiu resolver isso?

Answer (score 1):

Olá, isto serve?

O atributo **download** faz baixar o ficheiro que está no **href**.

```js
function mudarLink() {
  var baixar = document.getElementById('baixar');
  baixar.href = "http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/share-sprite-new.svg?v=24e64812c790";
  baixar.innerHTML = "Baixar imagem Stack Exchange";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="mudarLink()">Mude o Link</button>
<a id="baixar" href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/br/img/sprites.svg?v=e26b234630f5" download>Baixar imagem Stack Overflow</a>
```

**Editado:**

Atenção que não funciona em todos os navegadores:
http://caniuse.com/#feat=download

Comment: Isto serve em partes, preciso que o argumento para o href seja dinâmico, ou seja, variável de acordo com o arquivo que o usuário escolher. Estou usando um programa em cobol, porém a parte de download precisa ser feita em javascript.

Comment: Dá para mudar o **href** com javascript. Talvez: `document.getElementById("id").href = "link";`. 
Veja a resposta editada para em exemplo de como usar.

Comment: rESOLVEU @RicardoRibeiro

Answer (score 0):

meu problema era: fazer download após selecionar um option resolvi assim:

```
<select id="tipo_documento" name="tipo_documento">
<option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">.:: Modelos de Documentos ::.</option>
<option value="Documentos/DayCamp/Contrato.doc">Contrato.doc</option>
<option value="Documentos/DayCamp/Orçamento.doc">Orçamento.doc</option>
</select>

<a href="#" download id="btnBaixarModelo" name="btnBaixarModelo" class="btn bg-purple form-control pull-right"  title="Baixar Modelo">
<i class="fa fa-cloud-download mao" title="Baixar Modelo"></i>
</a>

$('#frmOrcamento #tipo_documento').on('change',function(){
var url = $(this).val();$('#frmOrcamento #btnBaixarModelo').attr({'href':url});
})
```

Sei que "download" não funciona em alguns navegadores, porém meu cliente utiliza chrome e firefox.
Regra do negócio: ao selecionar um option ele copia e cola o caminho para o link do botão[ class .btn => bootstrap ]

Tente criar algo semelhante, é possível que essa minha idéia te ajude, sucesso!